# SpringBoot logging configuration based on logging level

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, slf4j

Is it possible to specify in SpringBoot's appliaction.properties different logging configuration for different logging levels?
For example to log info to file but debug only to console and specify different format for them.
I searched in [SpringBoot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the log4j2 logger and specifiying withing its configurating file multiple logger elements. If you have the log4j2 dependency set up in spring, it should pick up the configuration in the file **log4j2-spring.xml**. Take a look at their intro docs [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html), but i believe something like this in the log4j2 config file would suffice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%throwable"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="FileAppender" fileName="debug.log">
           <PatternLayout>
             <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
           </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        </Root>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following config in your `application.yml`

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    com:
      somepackage: DEBUG
      someotherpackage: TRACE
```

Here you have set default logging to `INFO` (root logger) and for package `com.somepackage` logging level is `DEBUG`, for `com.someotherpackage` logging level is `TRACE`.